# Closed form for sine graphic rotated by 45 degrees?

Tags: functions

Is there a non-parametric closed form for a function looking like a sine rotated 45 degrees?

I have encountered also a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53758/what-is-a-function-to-represent-a-diagonal-sine-wave) but it asks for a function resembling the rotated sine, but not necessarily exact.

Comment: The second answer in your linked question explains exactly what you want.

Comment: @flawr no, I do not want parametrically defined curve, I want a ***closed form***.

Comment: This parametric expression is in *closed form*. What you mean is a nonparametric expression.

Comment: A parametrical definition is a closed form. - But I (and I think most others) know what you mean, I won't rule out that it exists, but it ain't going to be pretty.

Comment: If you are looking for an expression of the form $f(x)=..$ then you have to ask yourself if the "rotated" sine is actually a *function*: would each $x$ have only one corresponding value $f(x)$?

Comment: @m.a. yes, it is a function, everywhere defined, having a unique value.

Comment: You will only encounter some points where it is not differentiable at the original zeros of the sine (depending on what is the dependent variable this will be at the even / odd multiples of $\pi$).

Comment: Essentially, if you want to express $t+\sin t$ as a function of $t-\sin t$, you need a closed-form expression for the inverse function of $t-\sin t=\frac{t^3}{6}-\frac{t^4}{24}+\frac{t^5}{120}-\ldots$.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio yes.

Comment: Then, have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem.

Comment: @Henrik parametric expression is a closed form but for curve rather than for the function. Similarly, closed form for inverse function is not a closed form for straight function.

Comment: @Anixx [Doesn't look like a function to me...](http://i.imgur.com/QXAnarT.png)

Comment: @Jack M this graph is wrong. It is rotated 60 degrees

Comment: @Anixx You're correct, my software was in radians rather than degrees, so that's $45$ radians or about $60$ degrees. The $45$ degree one does indeed look plausibly function-like.

Answer (score -1):

Let $(X_0,Y_0)$ be a point on the rotated graph. Then, converting to polar coordinates, the point is $(\sqrt{X_0^2+Y_0^2},arctan \frac{Y_0}{X_0})$. Rotating 45 deg. gives  ($\sqrt{X_0^2+Y_0^2},arctan \frac{Y_0}{X_0}$+45 deg.$)$. That is $(\sqrt{X_0^2+Y_0^2}cos(arctan \frac{Y_0}{X_0}+45$ deg.$),\sqrt{X_0^2+Y_0^2}sin(arctan \frac{Y_0}{X_0}+45$ deg.$))$ in Cartesian coordinates. If this point is $(x,y)$, then $y=sin$ $x$, so the closed form $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}sin(arctan \frac{y}{x}+45$ deg.$)=sin(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}cos(arctan \frac{y}{x}+45$ deg.$)$ works.
For $45$ deg. rotation clockwise instead, change $+45$ deg. to $+45$ deg.

Comment: It is clear from the comments that this is not what OP wants.